# How pass angular 2 front end form data to lumen api BackEnd

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, angular2-forms, lumen, bootstrap-grid

I am new to angular2 and lumen framework. I developed my web application as two separated project then 
                    -> frontend - angular2-> backend - lumen

now I have developed the Backend function to update a user when transfer Jason object from postmen like

`{
"salutation":"Mr",
"name":"Test Name",
"lastname":"Test last name", 
"email":"testUser@gmail.com",
"address":"123/1, Village, some text"
}`

it is update the table correctly.

In my fronted I have a form with angular2. It is like [image]

Then I want to know how create the relationship to update the table with Lumen.
my api url is ->

http://localhost:8000/v1/passenger/1/updatePassenger.

Can anyone explain the mechanism to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You should first use data binding to get the data from the view to your component then use the http client module to send this data to the api backend then you get your respond.

See this link
https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#patch

And u need to override Cross origin if you are using localhost for testing purposes

Comment: is it angular2. Should i create a service